# How to customize the image with Log Analytics virtual machine extension using Azure Image Builder

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-image-builder

I have created a Windows VM with Azure Image Builder using PowerShell by following this documentation.

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $imageResourceGroup,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $location,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $imageTemplateName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $runOutputName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $myGalleryName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]
  $imageDefName
)

## Register features
Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute, Microsoft.KeyVault, Microsoft.Storage, Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages, Microsoft.Network |
Where-Object RegistrationState -ne Registered |
Register-AzResourceProvider

## Install modules
#Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity -RequiredVersion 0.7.2 -Force
#Install-Module -Name Az.ImageBuilder -Force

## Your Azure Subscription ID
$subscriptionID = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id
Write-Output $subscriptionID

## Create a resource group
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $imageResourceGroup -Location $location

## Create user identity and set role permissions
[int]$timeInt = $(Get-Date -UFormat '%s')
$imageRoleDefName = "Azure Image Builder Image Def $timeInt"
$identityName = "myIdentity$timeInt"

## Create a user identity.
New-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Name $identityName

## Store the identity resource and principal IDs in variables.
$identityNameResourceId = (Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Name $identityName).Id
$identityNamePrincipalId = (Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Name $identityName).PrincipalId

## Assign permissions for identity to distribute images
$myRoleImageCreationUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azvmimagebuilder/master/solutions/12_Creating_AIB_Security_Roles/aibRoleImageCreation.json'
$myRoleImageCreationPath = "$env:TEMP\myRoleImageCreation.json"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myRoleImageCreationUrl -OutFile $myRoleImageCreationPath -UseBasicParsing

$Content = Get-Content -Path $myRoleImageCreationPath -Raw
$Content = $Content -replace '<subscriptionID>', $subscriptionID
$Content = $Content -replace '<rgName>', $imageResourceGroup
$Content = $Content -replace 'Azure Image Builder Service Image Creation Role', $imageRoleDefName
$Content | Out-File -FilePath $myRoleImageCreationPath -Force

## Create the role definition.
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $myRoleImageCreationPath

## Grant the role definition to the image builder service principal.
$RoleAssignParams = @{
  ObjectId           = $identityNamePrincipalId
  RoleDefinitionName = $imageRoleDefName
  Scope              = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/resourceGroups/$imageResourceGroup"
}
New-AzRoleAssignment @RoleAssignParams

## Create an Azure Compute Gallery
## Create the gallery.
#$myGalleryName = 'myImageGallery'
#$imageDefName = 'winSvrImages'

New-AzGallery -GalleryName $myGalleryName -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Location $location

## Create a gallery definition.
$GalleryParams = @{
  GalleryName       = $myGalleryName
  ResourceGroupName = $imageResourceGroup
  Location          = $location
  Name              = $imageDefName
  OsState           = 'generalized'
  OsType            = 'Windows'
  Publisher         = 'myCo'
  Offer             = 'Windows'
  Sku               = 'Win2019'
}
New-AzGalleryImageDefinition @GalleryParams

## Create an image
## Create an Azure image builder source object.
$SrcObjParams = @{
  SourceTypePlatformImage = $true
  Publisher               = 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
  Offer                   = 'WindowsServer'
  Sku                     = '2019-Datacenter'
  Version                 = 'latest'
}
$srcPlatform = New-AzImageBuilderSourceObject @SrcObjParams

## Create an Azure image builder distributor object.
$disObjParams = @{
  SharedImageDistributor = $true
  ArtifactTag            = @{tag = 'dis-share' }
  GalleryImageId         = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/resourceGroups/$imageResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/$myGalleryName/images/$imageDefName"
  ReplicationRegion      = $location
  RunOutputName          = $runOutputName
  ExcludeFromLatest      = $false
}
$disSharedImg = New-AzImageBuilderDistributorObject @disObjParams

## Create an Azure image builder customization object.
$ImgCustomParams01 = @{
  PowerShellCustomizer = $true
  CustomizerName       = 'settingUpMgmtAgtPath'
  RunElevated          = $false
  Inline               = @("mkdir c:\\buildActions", "mkdir c:\\buildArtifacts", "echo Azure-Image-Builder-Was-Here  > c:\\buildActions\\buildActionsOutput.txt")
}
$Customizer01 = New-AzImageBuilderCustomizerObject @ImgCustomParams01

## Create a second Azure image builder customization object.
$ImgCustomParams02 = @{
  FileCustomizer = $true
  CustomizerName = 'downloadBuildArtifacts'
  Destination    = 'c:\\buildArtifacts\\index.html'
  SourceUri      = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azvmimagebuilder/master/quickquickstarts/exampleArtifacts/buildArtifacts/index.html'
}
$Customizer02 = New-AzImageBuilderCustomizerObject @ImgCustomParams02

## Create an Azure image builder template.
$ImgTemplateParams = @{
  ImageTemplateName      = $imageTemplateName
  ResourceGroupName      = $imageResourceGroup
  Source                 = $srcPlatform
  Distribute             = $disSharedImg
  Customize              = $Customizer01, $Customizer02
  Location               = $location
  UserAssignedIdentityId = $identityNameResourceId
}
New-AzImageBuilderTemplate @ImgTemplateParams

## To determine if the template creation process was successful, you can use the following example.
Get-AzImageBuilderTemplate -ImageTemplateName $imageTemplateName -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup |
Select-Object -Property Name, LastRunStatusRunState, LastRunStatusMessage, ProvisioningState

## Start the image build
## Submit the image configuration to the VM image builder service.
Start-AzImageBuilderTemplate -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Name $imageTemplateName

## Create a VM
## Store login credentials for the VM in a variable. The password must be complex.
$Cred = Get-Credential

## Create the VM using the image you created.
$ArtifactId = (Get-AzImageBuilderRunOutput -ImageTemplateName $imageTemplateName -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup).ArtifactId

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Image $ArtifactId -Name myWinVM01 -Credential $Cred

## Verify the customizations
Get-Content -Path C:\buildActions\buildActionsOutput.txt

Get-ChildItem c:\buildArtifacts\

## Delete the image builder template
#Remove-AzImageBuilderTemplate -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -Name $imageTemplateName

## Delete the image resource group
#Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name $imageResourceGroup
```

I want to add the Log Analytics virtual machine extension for Windows to the custom image.

Comment: Have you tried this `Set-AzVMExtension` Cmdlets  to enable log analytics extension as stated in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows#powershell-deployment

Comment: Venkatesh, Is it possible to include the log analytics extension, while building the custom image using Azure Image Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the same custom params that I see in your script, something in inline (Silent installation commands) comments with workid or key?

however, the easiest way is to enabled log analytics auto provisioning in security center now it's called microsoft defender for cloud (I am using it)